# DOC file type association with Office 2007 - Why does it not happen automatically?

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-office-2007

I have Windows Vista machine and I recently installed Office 2007 (I did not have earlier installations of any office product). The installation was a complete success with no error messages etc., however the association of DOC files with Office 2007 is not setup automatically. I have completed it manually now and it is working fine. My question is

1. Why did not the installation take care of this
2. How will I change the icon so that the DOC files look like Word 2007. I am not able to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to happen sometimes, the installer fails to write the registry values needed for the association. If it's only Word that you're having issues with you can try using a tool called [docfix](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/232/1/Unable-to-open-DOC-attachments-from-Windows-Mail.html). It's created to solve this issue.